# $rank\begin{pmatrix}f(A)\\g(A)\end{pmatrix}=rank\begin{pmatrix}f(A)&g(A)\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. For any polynomials $f,g$, show that $$rank\begin{pmatrix}f(A)\\g(A)\end{pmatrix}=rank\begin{pmatrix}f(A)&g(A)\end{pmatrix}.$$

I just could say $$rank\begin{pmatrix}f(A)\\g(A)\end{pmatrix}=rank\begin{pmatrix}f(A)'&g(A)'\end{pmatrix}.$$ Here $A'$ is the transpose of $A$.

The existence of invertible $P,Q$ such that $PAQ=diag(E_r,0)$ seems to give nothing, since we consider polynomials of $A$.

The Jordan canonical form seem also hit the target. Help.

Comment: Hint: $A$ is similar to $A^T$ because they have the same rational canonical form.

Comment: @user1551 OK, thank you, it is OK.